# Retrieve XML value from node with multiple attributes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to get the value of an xml node that has multiple attributes using xslt.

Here is a snippet of what the xml will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:Report_Data>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
         <wd:Account>Accrued Deferred Compensation</wd:Account>
         <wd:Summary_Level_01 wd:Descriptor="Descriptor_Text">
             <wd:ID wd:type="Summary_ID" wd:parent_id="UR_CHART_OF_ACCOUNTS" wd:parent_type="Account_ID">DESIRED VALUE</wd:ID>
         </wd:Ledger_Account_Summary_Level_01>-
    </wd:Report_Entry>
<Report_Data>
```

I want to get the text "DESIRED VALUE" into my output.
I can grab values like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="wd:Summary_Level_01/@wd:Descriptor"/>
```

How can I grab the desired value?

I tried using this (but this only works for single attribute elements):

```
<xsl:value-of select="Summary_Level_01/@wd:ID [@wd:type='Summary_ID']"/>
```

Could this be an xslt/xml processor issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example XML in your question is not namespace-well-formed as there's no namespace binding for the `wd:` prefix, but assuming that the real XML *is* namespace-well-formed and you've got the same prefixes mapped to the same namespace URIs in the stylesheet as you have in the source document, then you probably need something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="wd:Summary_Level_01/wd:ID[@wd:type='Summary_ID']"/>
```

The `wd:ID` is an *element*, not an attribute, so it doesn't need the `@` prefix.